# Using the one-liner syntax for controller specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write terse tests for an API controller, but I'm having trouble with the "one-liner" syntax offered by RSpec.

I'm overriding the subject explictly to refer to the *action* of posting rather than the *controller*:

```
let (:params) { some_valid_params_here }
subject { post :create, params }
```

When I use the one-liner syntax to test http_status, it works fine:

```
it { is_expected.to have_http_status(:created) }
# pass!
```

But when I try to use it for a different expectation, it blows up:

```
it { is_expected.to change{SomeActiveRecordModel.count}.by(1) }
# fail! "expected result to have changed by 1, but was not given a block"
```

Notably, when I run this second expectation in a longer form, calling on subject explictly, it works:

```
it "creates a model" do
  expect{ subject }.to change{SomeActiveRecordModel.count}.by(1)
end
# pass
```

Is this just a weakness of the one-liner syntax, that it can't handle this more complicated expression? Or have I misunderstood something about how subject is inferred into these tests?

(NB: I know that setting the subject to an action has some detractors, and I'm happy to hear opinions, but that isn't the aim of this question).

Comment: For API's I find request specs much more useful than controller specs as they actually go through the routing layer and you can write expectations about the JSON returned. The additional acuity is well worth the trade off of being ever so slightly slower.

Comment: @max This might be the way I end up going, but the question is really about RSpec rather than the surrounding context. If I change the above subject to a request rather than a controller action call, I'll still have the same problem.

Comment: @max I am grateful for the pointer, though! Looks like Rails 5 is deprecating controller tests, so I expect I will change some things unrelated to this question :)

Comment: "In Rails 5, controller tests are generated with superclass ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest instead of ActionController::TestCase which is deprecated . It will be moved into a separate gem in Rails 5.1 . " http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html

Comment: So controller tests are still around but they are now full stack instead of these wonky stubs that let you poke around inside the controller. RSpec has not really caught up yet though.

Comment: @max Yeah, that's the same Rails post I found, thanks. It looks like RSpec wants to follow suit in time: http://rspec.info/blog/2016/07/rspec-3-5-has-been-released/ (scroll down to 'support for rails 5').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this
`subject { -> { post :create, params } }`
and then
`it { is_expected.to change(SomeActiveRecordModel, :count).by(1) }`

Here you have very nice discussion about this
[github_topic](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/805)

Comment: I'd found that topic before, but hadn't managed to get it working. I'd got confused around the fact I've got two tests for different subjects running side by side - one on the request response, and one on the request itself.

I'll rework some things to separate it out properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said before there's a simple solution involving `subject` ; it does not require a `lambda` tho ; I applied it this way for my `CategoryController#show` :

```
describe '#show' do
  subject { get :show, id: category }

  context "as guest" do
    it { is_expected.to render_template('show') }
  end
end
```